# locate does not return hits for content of `~/Library`

Tags: macos, command-line, locate

I've got an iMac and I'm trying to find a file which is buried deep within my `Library` folder. Thinking I could find it quick and easily using `locate` from command prompt, I was surprised that my file was not found.  I wound up using `find` instead.

Does anyone know how to get `locate`'s data base to include content within my `~/Library` directory?

I suspect this may be a result of Mac making `~/Library` a hidden directory.  (While it's not hidden on the command line, it is hidden in `Finder`.)  So I guess I'm asking for two possible things:

1. How can I get the `locate` database to include content from `~/Library` but not every hidden directory?
2. How can I get the `locate` database to include hidden directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run [`updatedb`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/updatedb) first. Perhaps like this

```
updatedb --localpaths=~/Library
```